# Ioncube Loader M1 Mac using Dockerfile

Tags: php, macos, docker, apple-m1, ioncube

On the beginning I want to say that I am a beginner in Docker. As I know Ioncube releases don't support M1 Mac. Know a beta version for M1 Macs was released and I don't know how to downloaded using Dockerfile. How to write Dockerfile for Ioncube M1 release?

Comment: See https://github.com/GagalKoding/docker-lamp for a Dockerfile for M1 that includes Ioncube loader. I just started using this myself as an intro to Docker.

Answer (score 0):

In a `Dockerfile` this doesn't work any different than it would on the CLI; except the `RUN` prefix:

```
RUN wget https://www.ioncube.com/beta/ioncube_loader-osx_arm-20.3.tar.gz
```

Then just unpack, install the files; restart `php-fpm`, when necessary.